Why does Trump have a significantly higher support rate than Harris in the cryptocurrency sector polls?
Recently, I've been following the progress of the U.S. election and noticed some differences in support rates among the public through various channels. In a recent global poll in the cryptocurrency sector, it shows that Trump’s support rate is leading Harris by as much as 70%. I’m really curious—why does Trump have such high support in this field?  Can anyone tell me what’s driving this phenomenon?

People in "the cryptocurrency sector" are disproportionnately male, rich, white, interested in self-made-man stories (whether genuine or fake), skeptical about governement (and central bank), caracteristics  which all correlate positively with Trump's vote.

@Evargalo If you can find a source for that, then that would be a good answer.

Why is your name the same as the name of the site? You would not happen to be affiliated, would you?

@Evargalo - Interestingly, that is only mostly true. The study cited in my answer found that "Crypto owners are disproportionately men (22 percent, versus 9 percent of women), young, and members of racial minority groups. Thirteen percent of white voters say that they’ve owned crypto, compared to 17 percent of Black voters and 22 percent of Hispanics." There's probably a competition between the effect of Silicon Valley being biased to White people in general, and some Black people and other people of color being excluded from traditional banking (or also, more targeted by crypto scams?)

One actually sees a similar effect on global scale, incidentally, where while some countries decry cryptocurrency as a tool of wealthy American investors, others (e.g. El Salvador, Venezuela, even Russia, which had banned it) have seen it as a possible way to free themselves from an international financial system that they see as biased against them.

Because he is promising to not regulate crypto currency and to fire people who want to.
Trump vows to sack top financial regulator in crypto backing

Nashville | Donald Trump says he would fire the Securities and
Exchange Commission chairman and pick crypto-friendly regulators if he
returns to the White House, in a bid to court virtual currency
enthusiasts and harness the industry’s growing influence in the
political arena.
“This afternoon, I’m laying out my plan to ensure that the United
States will be the crypto capital of the planet and the bitcoin
superpower of the world and we’ll get it done,” Mr Trump said at a
bitcoin conference in Nashville on Saturday (Sunday AEST).

Trump Pledges to Fire Gensler, Pick Regulators Who ‘Love’ Crypto

Donald Trump said he would fire the Securities and Exchange Commission
chair and pick crypto-friendly regulators if he returns to the White
House in a bid to court virtual currency enthusiasts and harness the
industry’s growing influence in the political arena.


I guess that explains the donations too https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57444/has-the-cryptocurrencies-industry-become-the-2nd-largest-election-related-corpor

To supplement the other answer, which is correct, I'd also like to submit a frame challenge: the disparity is not likely to be as great as the question implies.
The website mentioned in the question, which curiously has the same name as the querent, is a single forum that employs what appears to be volunteer sampling. This sampling technique, while convenient, may easily introduce biases, due to the people who use a site not being representative of a larger population. In this case, the suspicion would be that the site might disproportionately attract the more ideological cryptocurrency holders.
Furthermore, despite the website claiming to implement the best possible "anti-sybil measures" (i.e. techniques to prevent multiple voting), it seems unlikely that they could prevent a technically sophisticated user from casting multiple votes via multiple IP addresses, at least with the kind of anomaly detection or de-aliasing techniques that they could employ; cryptocurrency enthusiasts, of course, tend to be quite good with computers. While the effort involved would be far too great for most people, the nature of anonymous volunteer internet voting on this rather small scale is such that even a single person could tilt the results substantially if they were able to successfully obscure their use of multiple IP addresses. One could automate the use of hundreds or even tens of thousands of IP addresses, unlike in-person voting, where physical travel is a limitation, or even the more secure verification methods employed in formal electronic voting systems.
There's also the concern about how trustworthy the site owners themselves are, of course.
There have been a few independent surveys of correlation between cryptocurrency and support for Donald Trump and Kamala Harris. One such study, from a few months ago, showed Harris at 38% and Trump at 50% among people with cryptocurrency investments. While this 12% lead would be enviable in a general election, it is still far from the 77% lead that the website would suggest exists.
